# LeftBarButtonItem position is not correct

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a leftbarbuttonitem like this: 
[image]

with this code:

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "WhiteBackButton.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.backButtonSelected), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

I am using this image:
[image]

and it sends up looking pushed over like this:[image]

How do I stop it from pushing too far from the left?

Comment: Is it a real "back" button, like you did pushVC, and it want to do popVC, and it has the same color has the title (not visible on your screen shot and possible other nav buttons?) and there is nothing more? Because if that's the case, you may just have rename the previousvc.title to `" "` to do the trick before pushing that viewcontroller.

Comment: make sure that the image you are using does  not have white space

Comment: i did make sure that the image doesn't have white space

Comment: Your image has too much white space (well, really, zero-alpha space). Trim it on all sides, or at a minimum on the left.

Answer (score 1):

```
let negativeSpacer:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -10
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, leftBarButton]
```

Answer (score 0):

WhiteBackButton.png image most likely has white space around/in front of the arrow.

I suggest also be using:

UIBarButtonItem(image:style:target:action:) instead of UIButton it will simplify your code...

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init

If you are changing the barButtonItems a lot can extend ViewController with the following functions and add them to viewWillAppear:

```
//should have a left and right of each:
func addRightBarButtonWithImage(_ buttonImage: UIImage) {
    let rightButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: buttonImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.toggleRight))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}


func setNavigationBarItem() {
    self.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: “icon.png”)!)
    self.addRightBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: “icon.png”)!)

}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!